# Extend Class Without Repeating All Constructor Parameters?

Tags: magento2

I often find it annoying that I have to repeat all of the dependencies after extending a class. Am I missing a trick here?

For example the Block Template class only requires that you inject and pass two parameters to the parent. Would I have to create my own context object if I wanted to do something like that?

Comment: That's the point of inheritance, what exactly are you trying to do? What do you need to extend from the Block Template class?

Comment: I extend the template class into a block for my module, then I extend that block from another more specific block.

I don't want to have the DI in its full form twice, it's too verbose.

I'm aware of what inheritance is meant for, I was wondering if there was a Magento trick like the way they pass context and data alone.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly in the Template block class are you extending/changing?

Comment: Your question is irrelevant, I'm adding custom functions and injecting more classes.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart.php

Comment: Ok, if you say so. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar need and wish if I could use params in _constructor instead (note single _, there is a __constructor and _constructor in Magento). Unfortunately it ends up with _construct *should be compatible with parent _construct* anyway.

It is possible to use objectManager as a not well optimized workaround.

```
/**
 * Model construct that should be used for object initialization
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->emailConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\LCB\ContactForms\Model\Email\Template\Config::class);
    parent::_construct();
}
```

An answer why to do that is obvious. You don't have to worry that you constructor will be not compatible between various Magento 2 versions. Magento2 plugin is way better solution instead class rewrite but still, you can't modify protected methods with it.